# $0.x3+0.3x=\frac{7}{9} \implies x=?$ An old book problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, math-history, fractions

I was trying to solve some of problems in an old very old book , which not signed 
 $$0.3\times x ,\\0.\overline{3}\times x \\ 0.\overline{3x} $$ to solve below equation . I tried like below .
My question : How many way we can read this question ?
Am I right ?
$$0.x3+0.3x=\frac{7}{9}$$

$$\quad{0.\overline{x3}+0.\overline{x3}=\frac{7}{9}\\(\frac{\overline{x3}}{100}+\frac{\overline{x3}}{10000}+...)+
(\frac{\overline{3x}}{100}+\frac{\overline{3x}}{10000}+...)\\
(\dfrac{\dfrac{\overline{3x}}{100}}{1-\frac{1}{100}})+(\dfrac{\dfrac{\overline{x3}}{100}}{1-\frac{1}{100}})=\\\frac{\overline{x3}}{99}+\frac{\overline{3x}}{99}=\\
\frac{\overline{x3}+\overline{3x}}{99}=\\
\frac{10x+3+30+x}{99}=\\\frac{x+3}{9} \to \\\frac{x+3}{9}=\frac{7}{9} \\x=4}$$

Comment: In line 3 aplly $\times \frac{100}{100} to fractions $

Comment: Why are people downvoting ? You are not interested ? Leave the discussion. Thats completely impolite. +1 for presenting an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\quad{0.\overline{x3}+0.\overline{3x}=\frac{7}{9}\\0.\overline{x}\times 3+0.\overline{3x}=\frac{7}{9}\\
0.\overline{x3}+0.\overline{3}\times x=\frac{7}{9}
\\0.\overline{x}\times 3+0.\overline{3}\times x=\frac{7}{9}\\or \\0.3\times x+0.x\times 3=\frac{7}{9}\\0.(3x)+0.(x3)=\frac{7}{9}}$$ is there an other possible reading  ?